# Auto resize cells within table

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I auto resize the column width or row height in a PowerPoint table?

Edit: I am working with PowerPoint 2010 and I wanted something like:

```
Sub table_fix()
 Dim icol As Integer, irow As Integer, minW As Single, minH As Single
 With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).table
  For icol = 1 To .Columns.Count
   For irow = 1 To .Rows.Count
    With .Cell(irow, icol).Shape.TextFrame
     If minW = 0 Then minW = .TextRange.BoundWidth + .MarginLeft + .MarginRight
     If minW < .TextRange.BoundWidth + .MarginLeft + .MarginRight Then minW = .TextRange.BoundWidth + .MarginLeft + .MarginRight
    End With
   Next
   .Columns(icol).Width = minW
  Next
 End With
 With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).table
  For irow = 1 To .Rows.Count
   For icol = 1 To .Columns.Count
    With .Cell(irow, icol).Shape.TextFrame
     If minH = 0 Then minH = .TextRange.BoundHeight + .MarginTop + .MarginBottom
     If minH < .TextRange.BoundHeight + .MarginTop + .MarginBottom Then minH = .TextRange.BoundHeight + .MarginTop + .MarginBottom
    End With
   Next
   .Rows(irow).Height = minH
  Next
 End With
End Sub
```

This code does not fix all column widths and all row heights. It has some mess ups on which columns to resize when the columns are narrow and high and it adds random spaces on some numbers sometimes.

I was hoping I could simulate "resizing of a cell through double clicking on the border". I believe I need to have some kind of iteration calculation with `BoundWidth` and `BoundHeight` or does 2010 have my originally searched for feature?

Edit 2: I have split the code for testing:

```
Sub IT()
 Dim icol As Integer, irow As Integer, minW As Single, minH As Single
 Call max_it
 Call size_it
End Sub

Function max_it()
 With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).table
  For icol = 1 To .Columns.Count
   .Columns(icol).Width = 1000
  Next
 End With
End Function

Function size_it()
 With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).table
  For icol = 1 To .Columns.Count
   For irow = 1 To .Rows.Count
    With .Cell(irow, icol).Shape.TextFrame
     If minW = 0 Then minW = .TextRange.BoundWidth + .MarginLeft + .MarginRight
     If minW < .TextRange.BoundWidth + .MarginLeft + .MarginRight Then minW = .TextRange.BoundWidth + .MarginLeft + .MarginRight
    End With
   Next
   .Columns(icol).Width = minW
   minW = 0
   If icol < .Columns.Count Then .Columns(icol + 1).Width = 1000
  Next
  For irow = 1 To .Rows.Count
   For icol = 1 To .Columns.Count
    With .Cell(irow, icol).Shape.TextFrame
     If minH = 0 Then minH = .TextRange.BoundHeight + .MarginTop + .MarginBottom
     If minH < .TextRange.BoundHeight + .MarginTop + .MarginBottom Then minH = .TextRange.BoundHeight + .MarginTop + .MarginBottom
    End With
   Next
   .Rows(irow).Height = minH
  Next
 End With
End Function
```

When I run `max_it` and `size_it` separately, it does what I want, but if I call IT to run the two functions after each other it ignores the `max_it` part and therefore the `size_it` will not return the correct `BoundWidth` if the cells are "narrow and high".

I may have some beginner's mistake, like: VBA is smart and realizes that the first max_it changes will be redone by `size_it` and therefore ignores the code (?)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "auto resize"?  Do you mean that you want to resize the table via code (ie, automate the process) or something else?  Also, it's *always* a good idea to mention which version of PPT you're working in and which versions your code needs to support.

Comment: i fixed the "random" screw ups by setting minW/minH = 0 after they have been assigned to the Width/Height. On the narrow&high cells I have tried to assign huge values to the cells width before checking the boundwidth, but that does not work in one run. If I first run a macro that widens the column and afterwards mine it is fine, but in one macro (even with the two a seperate function) it doesn't work, any help?

Comment: Do you have any error trapping enabled?  The table object model in 2007 and 2010 never got properly finished, especially when you get down to the Shape level.  Lots of properties/methods that appear in Intellisense/the docs simply don't work when it comes to table cell shapes.  The code will compile but will error when it hits certain statements.  If your code runs in an On Error Resume Next context, you'll won't see any errors.

Comment: no errors at all, it just seems to ignore that I increase the width first before I am trying to find the minimum width (this to me seems like the best way to get the "auto width" since BoundWWidth would return the width the cell needs, instead of the space it currently has, which it does if I do not widen the cell first)

Comment: I finally have gotten around to look into this issue again and am still nowhere to solve it. I have added a line to increase the width of the column before looking for the minimum width, nevertheless VBA seems to not be able to read out the correct boundwidth, can I reload the boundwidth data somehow (I assume it uses the boundwidth prior to resizing...

Comment: If I enter a break point within the while loop where the minW is assigned (any of the lines) my code does what I want, if I do not enter a breakpoint and run the macro without "supervision" it continues to fail on resizing tall and narrow columns... is this a bug? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit on internet and did some R&D and found this code which worked on a table. The Scenario is that there is a slide and a table in it with a row selected.

```
Sub Spacer_Row() 'backup
Dim Sld As Slide
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim tabs As table
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
'Table row formatting
On Error GoTo Select_Object
With ActiveWindow.Selection
If .ShapeRange.Type = msoTable Then
Set tabs = .ShapeRange.table
For lRow = 1 To tabs.Rows.Count
 For lCol = 1 To tabs.Columns.Count
  If tabs.Cell(lRow, lCol).Selected Then
   With tabs.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
    tabs.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame2.MarginBottom = 0.7
    tabs.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame2.MarginTop = 0.6
    tabs.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 1
    tabs.Rows(lRow).Height = 0.2
    tabs.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
   End With
  End If
 Next
Next
Exit Sub
End If
Select_Object:
 MsgBox "Select a row to resize" 'Error box asking to select a row
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me just for auto-resizing Columns, hopefully one day someone will complement it to auto-resizing Rows too, basically when you autofit a column, it makes sure all the cells in the column have at most 1 line.

Using that same logic, I increased each cell's width until it had only one line, you can change the increment depending on how critical it's for you to have the cell right border close to the end of the text inside your cell:

```
For j = 1 To pptTable.Columns(1).Cells.count
    If pptTable.Cell(j, 1).Shape.HasTextFrame Then
    Do While pptTable.Cell(j, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Lines.count > 1
        pptTable.Columns(1).Width = pptTable.Columns(1).Width + 5
    Loop
    End If
    'pptCell.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText
 Next
```

You could even make it better by taking the previous cell's width and if it's greater than the current cell's width, you just put it and advance the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it worked by first find the right border cell coordinates then stimulate double click on it.

```html
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitMessage Lib "user32" () As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10

Private Sub SingleClick()
  SetCursorPos 100, 100 'x and y position
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub

Private Sub DoubleClick(x, y)
  'Double click as a quick series of two clicks
  SetCursorPos x, y 'x and y position
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub

Private Sub RightClick()
  'Right click
  SetCursorPos 200, 200 'x and y position
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub

Public Sub Wait(Seconds As Double)
    Dim endtime As Double
    endtime = DateTime.Timer + Seconds
    Do
        WaitMessage
        DoEvents
    Loop While DateTime.Timer < endtime
End Sub

Sub Button1()
    
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim oShp As Shape
    Dim oCell As cell
    'Determine Which Shape is Active
      If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
        'Loop in case multiples shapes selected
           For Each oShp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
                If oShp.Type = msoTable Then
                    Set oTbl = oShp.Table
                    For lRow = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
                        For lCol = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
                         If oTbl.cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.HasTextFrame Then
                          With oTbl.cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
                           oTbl.cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.MarginLeft = 5
                           oTbl.cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.MarginRight = 5
                           
                           x = ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(oTbl.cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.Left + oTbl.cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.Width)
                           'need some adjustment
                           If lCol = oTbl.Columns.Count Then x = x - 7 Else x = x - 3
                            
                           y = ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY((oTbl.cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.Top + oTbl.cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.Height) / 2)
                           DoubleClick x, y
                            Wait 0.5
                          End With
                          End If
                         Next
                        Next
                End If
           Next oShp
      Else
        MsgBox "There is no shape currently selected!", vbExclamation, "No Shape Found"
      End If
    
End Sub
```