# Removing white space of table rows in PowerPoint using macros

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have been hustling to fix the table content that is exceeding slide height and width. In order to do this I tried shrinking text size in table(As you see in picture, the font size is changed to 9 from 14)
The other technique I am planning to use is, to eliminate excess 'white/empty space' present in each row of table by decreasing height(marked as blue).

Please help me to sharp my thoughts or any information to achieve this.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUjMe.png)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340726/auto-resize-cells-within-table) may be of use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes advantage of the fact that PowerPoint will never shrink row heights to less than the height of text contained in the cells. It will keep on shrinking text until the table fits on the slide.

```
Sub CheckTableHeight()
  Dim oSlide As Slide
  Dim oShape As Shape
  Dim oTable As Table
  Dim Row&, Column&
  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
      If oShape.HasTable Then
        Set oTable = oShape.Table
        Do Until oShape.Height + oShape.Top < ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight
          For Row& = 1 To oTable.Rows.Count
            oTable.Rows(Row&).Height = 5
            For Column& = 1 To oTable.Columns.Count
              oTable.Cell(Row&, Column&).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = (oTable.Cell(Row&, Column&).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size - 1)
            Next Column&
          Next Row&
        Loop
      End If
    Next oShape
  Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I found that, it will be quiet effective if we remove blank spaces at end of each text either in text boxes/ tables/ charts. Could you please share your thoughts on this..

Comment: Loop through all text looking for pairs of spaces. When the search stops returning results, then search for pairs of space and returns. Then the row height adjustment will minimize the row height to visible text.