# How do I properly auto-resize "overset" in tables in PowerPoint via VBA script?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following scenario: An "original" PowerPoint, and a translated PowerPoint (so the original has been translated). Problem is, that due to text expansion in the translated PowerPoint the tables have become too large to fit properly into the corresponding slide:

[image: translate table too large for slide]

So I've written this nifty (or so I thought) "auto-layouter" script that compares the size of the table in the original PowerPoint with the same table in the translated PowerPoint and then reduces the font size there until the table has about the same measurements as in the original (doesn't have to be absolutely exact, if, say the translated table is 5% bigger, that is okay):

```
Attribute VB_Name = "AutoLayoutPPT"
Sub AutoLayoutPPT()


'ORIG
Dim origPowerpointPresentation As Presentation
'#TO DO:
Set origPowerpointPresentation = PowerPoint.Presentations.Open("C:\Temp\orig_tables.pptx")


Dim origTablesList As New Collection   'ONLY height of PPT tables change, never the width during font resizing
For Each Slide In origPowerpointPresentation.Slides
     For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
         If Shape.HasTable = MsoTriState.msoTrue Then
             origTablesList.Add Shape.Height
         End If
     Next Shape
Next Slide


'TRANS
Dim transPowerpointPresentation As Presentation
Set transPowerpointPresentation = PowerPoint.Presentations.Open("C:\Temp\trans_tables.pptx")


Dim origHeightIndex As Integer
origHeightIndex = 0


'PowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Select   'SUPERIMPORTANT to SELECT slide first!!
For Each SlideTbl In transPowerpointPresentation.Slides
    SlideTbl.Select
    If SlideTbl.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = MsoTriState.msoTrue Then
        GoTo Breakout_Slides_Tables
    End If
    origHeightIndex = origHeightIndex + 1
    For Each ShapeTbl In SlideTbl.Shapes
        If ShapeTbl.HasTable = MsoTriState.msoTrue Then
            'Loop until the table's height is less than 10 units taller than the original height
            Do While ShapeTbl.Height > (origTablesList(origHeightIndex) + 10)
                For Row = 1 To ShapeTbl.Table.Rows.Count
                    For Column = 1 To ShapeTbl.Table.Columns.Count
                        If ShapeTbl.Table.Cell(Row, Column).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size <= 5 Then
                            GoTo Breakout_Tables
                        End If
                        ShapeTbl.Table.Cell(Row, Column).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = ShapeTbl.Table.Cell(Row, Column).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size - 1
                    Next Column
                Next Row
            Loop
        End If
Breakout_Tables:
Debug.Print "Prevented font reduction in table below 5"
    Next ShapeTbl
Breakout_Slides_Tables:
Next SlideTbl


For Each Slide In transPowerpointPresentation.Slides
    Slide.Select
    If Slide.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = MsoTriState.msoTrue Then
        GoTo Breakout_Slides
    End If
    For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
        If Shape.Type = MsoShapeType.msoGroup Then
            For Each ShapeGrp In Shape.GroupItems
                If ShapeGrp.HasTextFrame = MsoTriState.msoTrue Then
                    Do While ShapeGrp.TextFrame.TextRange.BoundWidth > ShapeGrp.Width Or ShapeGrp.TextFrame.TextRange.BoundHeight > ShapeGrp.Height
                        If ShapeGrp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size <= 5 Then
                            GoTo Breakout_Textboxes
                        End If
                        ShapeGrp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = ShapeGrp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size - 1
                    Loop
                End If
            Next ShapeGrp
        End If
        If Shape.Type <> MsoShapeType.msoGroup Then
            If Shape.HasTextFrame = MsoTriState.msoTrue Then
                Do While Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.BoundWidth > Shape.Width Or Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.BoundHeight > Shape.Height
                    If Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size <= 5 Then
                        GoTo Breakout_Textboxes
                    End If
                    Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size - 1
                Loop
            End If
        End If
Breakout_Textboxes:
Debug.Print "Prevented font reduction in table below 5"
    Next Shape
Breakout_Slides:
Next Slide


End Sub
```

But as you can see, it doesn't work properly as the font of the translated table has been reduced much too much, much more than necessary:
[image: result]

Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I normally first try by reducing the internal margins (I mean, when I am manually formatting slides). Then I pass to the reduction of the line spacing, if I still need to shrink the cells. I reduce the font size only as a last resort.

Comment: You can also try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992014/removing-white-space-of-table-rows-in-powerpoint-using-macros